# Find all duplicate values across two columns and make a single distinct row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science, data-analysis

I have a df with two columns IP address and user id. I am attempting to determine the distinct values across both the user id and the IP addresses. I know how to get a distinct list of users per IP and vis versa, but can't figure out if I wanted them smashed into a single row and how I'd do it.

what's the recommended way to get this result I'm looking for?

**Example Data:**

| ip_address | user_id |
| --- | --- |
| 127.0.0.1 | 111 |
| 192.168.1.1 | 111 |
| 127.0.0.1 | 444 |
| 10.10.0.1 | 555 |
| 8.8.8.8 | 666 |
| 8.8.8.8 | 888 |
| 8.8.8.8 | 999 |
| 10.0.0.1 | 777 |

**Final Format:**

| ip_address | user_id |
| --- | --- |
| 127.0.0.1, 192.168.1.1 | 111, 444, 555 |
| 8.8.8.8 | 666, 888, 999 |
| 10.0.0.1 | 777 |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use `networkx` to find the connected components, then `groupby.agg`:

```
import networkx as nx

# build graph
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, 'ip_address', 'user_id')

# create a dictionary to cluster connected nodes
d = {n:i for i,g in enumerate(nx.connected_components(G)) for n in g}

# map clusters
group = df['ip_address'].map(d)

# groupby.agg
out = (df.astype(str)
         .groupby(group, as_index=False)
         .agg(lambda x: ', '.join(dict.fromkeys(x)))
      )

print(out)
```

Output:

```
               ip_address        user_id
0  127.0.0.1, 192.168.1.1       111, 444
1               10.10.0.1            555
2                 8.8.8.8  666, 888, 999
3                10.0.0.1            777
```

*NB. I am assuming here that the values in both columns are not overlapping. If you had similar type of data in both columns (e.g ip addresses) and did not want to cross merge the groups (e.g. if `777` was `127.0.0.1` this would merge the first and last group), then you would need to add a unique identifier for each column (e.g. `A:127.0.0.1`/`B:127.0.0.1`).*