# Combine two lists together with Python

Tags: python, dataframe, list

I have this data set.

```
Group,Item
X40880,100-879045
160773,100-879045
160773,100-DGMX2-5-PP-BH-B-30
X52625,100-DGMX2-5-PP-BH-B-30
160773,110-879045
X40880,110-879045
221719,110-DGMX2-5-PP-BH-B-30
X52625,110-DGMX2-5-PP-BH-B-30
4533,600-34442
4533,650-34442
4533,390-33111K
```

```
import pandas as pd

# Read the CSV file into a DataFrame
df = pd.read_csv('./item.csv')  

# Create dictionaries to map items to groups and groups to items
item_to_groups = {}
group_to_items = {}

# Iterate through the DataFrame to populate the dictionaries
for _, row in df.iterrows():
    group = row['Group']
    item = row['Item']

    if group not in group_to_items:
        group_to_items[group] = list()

    if item not in item_to_groups:
        item_to_groups[item] = list()

    group_to_items[group].append(item)
    item_to_groups[item].append(group)

# Create the final output DataFrame
output_data = []
# already added
already_added = []

for group, items in group_to_items.items():
    if group in already_added:
        continue
    common_groups = []
    common_items = []
    for item in items:
        common_groups += item_to_groups[item]
    for group in common_groups:
        common_items += group_to_items[group]
        already_added.append(group)

    common_groups = set(common_groups)
    common_items = set(common_items)
    output_data.append([','.join(map(str, common_groups)), ','.join(map(str, common_items))])

# Create the final output DataFrame
final_df = pd.DataFrame(output_data, columns=['GROUPS', 'ITEMS'])

final_df.to_csv('./output.csv', index=False)

print(final_df)
# Print the final output DataFrame
final_df.head()
```

With above code, it will combine, and "Item" and "Group" as follows:

```
GROUPS  ITEMS
X40880,160773            110-879045,100-879045,100-DGMX2-5-PP-BH-B-30
221719,X52625,160773             110-DGMX2-5-PP-BH-B-30,110-879045,100-879045,100-DGMX2-5-PP-BH-B-30
4533                 600-34442,390-33111K
```

As 110-879045,100-879045,100-DGMX2-5-PP-BH-B-30 ITEMS are duplicated in 110-DGMX2-5-PP-BH-B-30,110-879045,100-879045,100-DGMX2-5-PP-BH-B-30 ITEMS set, I wanted to combine both lists together.

Expected output:

```
GROUPS  ITEMS
X40880,160773,221719,X52625         110-DGMX2-5-PP-BH-B-30,110-879045,100-879045,100-DGMX2-5-PP-BH-B-30
4533                                600-34442,390-33111K
```

Could you please help on this. Thank you.

Comment: Hi Casper, welcome to our community. You could augment your chances of getting a better answer if you give an example more didactic and instructive. You could replace your dataset with dummy data that still represents the problem you want to solve. This also has the benefit to help other users to quickly identify if your problem is also their problem.

Comment: I think `650-34442` is missing in the *last row-2nd column* of your expected output. Anyways, the linked duplicate should give you exactly what you want. You just need to slightly adjust *mozway*'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73751303/16120011) by changing `ip_adress` to `Group`and `user_id` to `Item`.

Comment: sorry, I have missed 650-34442. This also needs to be in 4533 GROUPS. 
4533 600-34442,390-33111K,650-34442
This link is addressing, my issue. Thank you